# import twitter posts in asp.net page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i am trying to import my posts in twitter in my asp.net page. i have tried the below code, but there is no result returned.

```
<a class="twitter-timeline"  href="https://twitter.com/omhisham2011" data-widget-id="MY     API key">Tweets</a>

<script>

!function (d, s, id)
{
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https'; if (!d.getElementById(id)) { js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = p + "://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); }
}
(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");</script>

    </div>
```

any help....

Answer (score 0):

Try this, taken directly from https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tfw-javascript

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-dnt=true href="https://twitter.com/omhisham2011" data-widget-id="Api Key">Tweets by user3261588</a>



  window.twttr = (function (d, s, id) {
      var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s);
      js.id = id;
      js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      return window.twttr || (t = {
          _e: [],
          ready: function (f) {
              t._e.push(f)
          }
      });
  }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
```